# data/data/app_name/filename not found

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am created a shared preference but my package name not created in my device storage location.

```
Context plutoContext = G.context.createPackageContext("me.test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences plutoPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(plutoContext);
                SharedPreferences.Editor plutoPrefEditor = plutoPreferences.edit();
                plutoPrefEditor.putString("Vehicles", response.toString());
                plutoPrefEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Mostly because you're looking in the **wrong** path.

Comment: I am using Sansung Phone..It has Android/data folder.But in that folder my package name not found

Comment: You can either: **1** - Google for that. **2** - Follow the link I provided.

Comment: I am installed my application in my phone

Comment: Not creating Shared Prefeance file

Comment: You're not looking in the right path, as I told you. And which is explained in the linked post.